# Unable to connect to a line side printer from a pod GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a private cluster with a pod running which prints a file to a network printer. The printer is accessible from VM's outside the cluster but it is not accessible from the pod. I am unable to ping the IP as well. DO we need some additional configuration in GKE to access the printer or say any application .?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the common things to check and do when you can't access services outside of your GKE cluster:

- Check if you can access the service from the GKE VM directly by SSHing into the VM and then doing ping/curl to verify connectivity
- Verify that the ip-masq-agent is running on the GKE cluster and that it's configured correctly
- Configure Cloud NAT for the network when you're using Private Clusters so you can still access internet resources

See more details for each these steps below:

### Verifying connectivity from the GKE node itself

SSH into the node and run ping / curl by running:

```
gcloud compute ssh my-gke-node-name --tunnel-through-iap
curl https://facebook.com
ping my-network-printer
```

### Verify ip-masq-agent configuration

Check if the ip-masq-agent Daemonset is running:

```
kubectl get ds ip-masq-agent -n kube-system
```

Verify that the ip-masq-agent configuration is set to ensure all RFC1918 addresses get masqueraded except the GKE node CIDR and pod CIDR:

```
kubectl describe configmaps/ip-masq-agent -n kube-system
```

Note the default configuration of ip-masq-agent most of the time has too many RFC1918 addresses included in the `nonMasqueradeCIDRs` setting. You need to ensure your external network printer isn't included in any of `nonMasqueradeCIDRs` ranges.
If it is included or the no CIDRs are set, then you should set the `nonMasqueradeCIDRs` to only include the GKE node CIDR and the GKE pod CIDR for your cluster. You can edit the configmap by running:

```
kubectl edit configmap ip-masq-agent --namespace=kube-system
```

More docs on GKE ip-masq-agent here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#edit-ip-masq-agent-configmap